What is the reason for Spring auth dependency error
I am using below spring dependencies in my project . I am getting error on application start up after added auth related code. This  is a leagacy project, so i cant use spring boot directly. Any help is appreciated
<spring.version>5.3.36</spring.version>
<spring-security.version>5.8.11</spring-security.version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.8</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency> 

Error logs on start up
improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
00:02:40.836 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.config.OAuth2ClientConfig] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: solvency2
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@59ec2012
]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.36.jar:5.3.36]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistrationRepository
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.36.jar:5.3.36]
        ... 59 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.89]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1120) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.89]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]*


This question is similar to: NoClassDefFoundError - org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistration when testing. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You are mixing jars from different Spring Security versions 5.8.11 and 5.7.8 which is always trouble waiting to happen.

you have shown us 7 rows from a full pom. If you are serious about asking for help then you should put some more effort into your question, as for starters actually providing an actual minimal pom.xml that has your error. Downvoted

Finally I was able to solve issue .Apart from spring-security-oauth2-client,I need to add one more dependency which solved issue

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

